# Kubernetes Pod internal communication

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 containers running in a single workload.

One container is running a Flask server application and the other is running an angular application.  I need to have this pod set up in a way where both applications can communicate with each other within the localhost. I need the angular container which is exposed in port 4200 to communicate with the unexposed flask server which is on port 5000. I am stuck when it comes to having these containers communicate within the pod.

Comment: All containers within a kubernetes pod share the same virtual network interface; so it should be as easy as using `localhost:5000` from the angular app to connect to the flask app. You may need to share more of your configurations

Comment: I have localhost:5000 specified in my angular application. There's no problem with communication on my local system. It's only an issue when when I put these 2 containers into a kubernetes workload/pod. When I deploy it as a service, I'm expecting the angular application to send data to my back-end flask application but I keep getting "http://localhost:5000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Comment: Can you share your deployment/pod configuration yaml? It could be an issue with your chosen cluster networking model as well.

Comment: @FGreg I would but I won't be able to post the entire thing. What should the cluster networking model look like?

Comment: When kubernetes was installed, the person installing it needed to pick a [Network Model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-implement-the-kubernetes-networking-model). If internal Pod communication is not working, that suggests there could be an issue in the network configuration of your cluster. I'd suggest writing a simple Pod spec with two containers and try using `netcat` or something similar to try communicating between the two containers. That way you can isolate if it's a network issue or something with your containers themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than localhost (`127.0.0.1`), make sure your flask server is reachable via *any* local IP, that is, `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`.

Comment: What are the cross origin requirements between angular containers and flask containers so that host 0.0.0.0 can be enabled in the flask server?

Comment: That has nothing to do with x-origin but with the fact that one has multiple IPs per (in this case) pod. I'm addressing it in http://troubleshooting.kubernetes.sh/#network as well. Did you actually try it?

Comment: This could be true. But do kubernetes pods have multiple IP addresses? Everything I've read (including https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#networking and https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/ among others) indicates that there should only be 1 IP address per Pod under normal circumstances.

Comment: No, the pods only have one IP, but localhost is a different one ;)

Comment: Hmmm I see your point. But in this case why would binding to `127.0.0.1` (localhost) be incorrect? In fact, you wouldn't want flask to bind to the non-loopback IP because it shouldn't be listening for packets from the non-loopback IP. It should only accept communication from localhost. My only point is, if this works it would seem there is a bug somewhere (idk if it would be Flask, k8s, the network plugin used, docker, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to communicate with each other using `localhost:<port-number>` as all containers in a Kubernetes pod share the same network namespace.

Comment: I have localhost:5000 specified in my angular application. There's no problem with communication on my local system. It's only an issue when when I put these 2 containers into a kubernetes workload/pod. When I deploy it as a service, I'm expecting the angular application to send data to my back-end flask application but I keep getting "http://localhost:5000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Comment: Can you post `kubectl describe pod <name-of-the-pod>`?